# Split string and copy value to another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a `varchar` column with a value like `1.23DOLLARS + 3.21EUROS`.

How can I split numbers and copy currency string to another column?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H5yMe.png)

Comment: Perhaps a bit pedantic but "dollar" is not a currency. Many currencies use the unit of dollar - e.g., USD, AUD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `string_split()` to split both side of `+` and then with `substring()` and `patindex()` you can get numbers and string parts seperated.

DB-Fiddle:

Schema and insert statements:

```
 create table testtables (currencyvalue varchar(100));
 insert into testtables values('1.23DOLLARS + 3.21EUROS');
```

Query:

```
 select substring(trim(value),1,PATINDEX('%[A-Za-z]%',trim(value))-1) price, 
 substring(trim(value),PATINDEX('%[A-Za-z]%',trim(value)),len(trim(value))) curr
 from
 testtables
 cross apply
 string_split( '1.23DOLLARS + 3.21EUROS','+') cs
```

Output:

| price | curr |
| --- | --- |
| 1.23 | DOLLARS |
| 3.21 | EUROS |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=617419d9f1a972b8c55c971be260c453)*